# Understanding a proof related to mollifiers

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am reading the proof of the following statement

> If $D^{\alpha}f$ exists weakly then $D^{\alpha}(f*\eta^{\epsilon}) = D^{\alpha}f* \eta^{\epsilon}$

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf (page 55, bottom)

We have;

$ D^{\alpha}\eta^{\epsilon}*f = \int D^{\alpha}_x\eta^{\epsilon}(x-y)f(y)$. How do I get the next step that

$\int D^{\alpha}_x\eta^{\epsilon}(x-y)f(y) = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int D^{\alpha}_y\eta^{\epsilon}(x-y)f(y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its just chain rule, I'll state a 1D version:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[f(x-y)] =f'(x-y) = -\frac{d}{dy}[f(x-y)]$$
since $$\frac{d}{dy}[f(x-y)] = f'(x-y) \cdot \underbrace{\frac{d}{dy}(x-y)}_{=-1}$$

Comment: It was that simple!

Comment: @Guest_000 indeed!